# What are the possible ways to convert SVG file to Raphael

Tags: javascript, svg, raphael

Let's say I saved some `.ai` file as `.svg`. Now I want to move all the vectors from this file to Raphael to manipulate them using JavaScript.

How can I do it? What are possible ways to achieve this goal? Please also write any pros and cons, so users will be able to choose best in their opinion way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could loop through the nodes of the SVG and write them to the Raphaël object one by one, but unless you are dealing with nonstandard element types/attributes you are better off using one of the Raphaël plugins that make importing SVGs a one-line command. Such as:

- https://github.com/crccheck/raphael-svg-import-classic
- https://github.com/wout/raphael-svg-import

Comment: +1 for a Raphael-only solution -- much better than getting Node involved, particularly for newer programmers

Comment: Totally agree with you @ChrisWilson. No Node solution is best for most users, and that's why I accepted this answer.

Comment: This won't help if you want to manipulate sub-elements of the svg... I prefer the rappar solution.

Answer (score 4):

I had to do exactly the same thing a few months ago. I used [**rappar**](https://github.com/DmitryBaranovskiy/rappar)

I used node from the command line to do the conversion and save it to a file

```
node rappar.js test.svg >test.js
```

test.js now contains the vectors. The only thing I did find though is that line 537 of rappar

```
var files = process.ARGV.slice(0);
```

should be

```
var files = process.argv.slice(0);
```

Other than that it worked a treat.

Answer (score 3):

I found some simple converter [here](http://readysetraphael.com/).

**Pros:**
It's really simple and straightforward - you upload the file, and get generated code. You can even see a preview of it. When you load really simple `.svg` it's working perfectly, and you can easily edit the code, but...

**Cons:**
But the biggest problem of it is that the code is a little bit messy. So if you load bigger file (100+ vectors, or even more; I loaded sth around 1000 for testing purposes). Also names and structure of it doesn't respond to layer's division. Sometimes some of the layers (you can see it in preview) are not in correct order, so if you want to see exactly the same 'image', you need to browse the code, looking which path correspond to which object in `.svg` file.

Anyway it's the only one I found, and in the end (after some work) you can achieve what you want. Best way to work with it is when you upload your .svg portion by portion, to avoid flood of messy code.

Comment: I think it's nice to see the actual name and address of the website, which isn't visible in your post. So here goes: Ready.Set.Raphael, http://readysetraphael.com/

Answer (score 2):

This one worked really well for me http://roomandboard.github.com/vectron/
When installing the rappar dependency at https://github.com/DmitryBaranovskiy/rappar you need to remove the Node.js code to get it to work.

Pros:
Not much code required.

Cons:
It can be a little slow on larger SVGs. You might want to consider saving it to JSON with another Raphael plugin to make the load faster the next time.

Answer (score -2):

All of the vectors are in the file, so you could put those paths to a variable string and Raphael wil use that.

Comment: Good point - you can open `.svg` as text file and copy it path by path, attribute by attribute... it will take some time but yeah - possible way indeed.

Comment: A programmatic solution like the ones offered above is MUCH better

Comment: To my knowledge, SVG coordinates are NOT the same as Raphael's, which is why we need a converter. One cannot simply copy and paste the coordinates from one toe the other. Isn't that why people came to this page - to find out how to convert them?